# Should I Switch to a Worm Composting Tube?

Tags: vermicomposting, worms

I'm thinking of taking my worm colony currently in a Rubbermaid and transferring it to one or two worm tubes in the ground outside. I read that red wigglers won't survive the winter but the cocoons do so that's cool. What are some methods that I can employ to ensure success for this switch?

Comment: Why not move part of your worms to the tubes in the ground? That way you can experiment without the risk of losing all your worms.

Comment: I could but we live in a townhome without a basement. A few worms have been escaping lately and it kinda freaks my wife out. So my options are to get it outside (preferred) or maybe the garage will work if there's a light on all the time.

Answer (score 3):

I am experimenting with this also. I lost most all of my worms this Summer due to the heat in Charlotte (95+) a lot this Summer. I keep mine in the garage but it still got to hot for them. So I am trying the in ground method. I did not use a tube , but  a 5 gallon bucket with a lid . I dug a hole big and deep enough to place the bucket up to its rim. I cut the bottom out and drilled a bunch of holes in the side. I moved some worms into the bucket and now dump veg scraps in the bucket and put the lid on. I am hoping that other worms will come in through the holes i cut in the side(1/4 inch ). I might should leave them in the garage till Summer and then move them to the in ground method. I am not sure they will survive the winter.